# Extract a string from a line between positions given by a pattern in another line

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I'm looking to output the characters between two positions A and B that are specified by the preceding line. Per pair, the two lines are equal in length, but among pairs the lengths can vary. Is there an efficient way (huge file sizes) to do it with `grep`, `sed`, or `awk`?

Example file:

```
xxxxxxAxxxxxxBxxxxxx
1234567890MNOPQRSTUV
xxAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxBxxxxxx
1234567890MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

...

I would like to obtain the output:

```
7890MNOP
34567890MNOPQRST
```

...

Comment: Are there other input lines that don't follow this pattern?  If so, should they be output unmodified or removed?

Comment: It is not completely clear, could the second line of each pair begin with an x?

Comment: ....or could "A" be on first position of the first line?

Comment: Should not matter, but the implied offset would. (If there is No A at all then start from beginning..) This is very familiar to mainframe people -  "Bounds" in ISPF edit. The OP examples have A and B as inclusive in the same way, so they could be mandatory or not but a null string or complementary "outer" substrings are not well defined.

Comment: All thanks for the great answers!!! My problem is solved and the scripts run very fast. If I could have marked more of them as favorite answers I would have!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```bsh
$ awk '!seen{match($0, /A.*B/);seen=1;next} {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);seen=0}' infile
7890MNOP
34567890MNOPQRST
```

**Explanation:** read in [man `awk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/awk.1posix.html):

```
RSTART
          The index of the first character matched by match(); 0 if no
          match.  (This implies that character indices start at one.)

RLENGTH
          The length of the string matched by match(); -1 if no match.

match(s, r [, a])  
          Return the position in s where the regular expression r occurs, 
          or 0 if r is not present, and set the values of RSTART and RLENGTH. (...)

substr(s, i [, n])
          Return the at most n-character substring of s starting at I.
          If n is omitted, use the rest of s.
```

Answer (score 7):

Although you can do this with AWK, I suggest Perl. Here's a script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $pattern = <>) {
    my $text = <>;
    my $start = index $pattern, 'A';
    my $stop = index $pattern, 'B', $start;
    print substr($text, $start, $stop - $start + 1), "\n";
}
```

You can name that script file whatever you like. If you were to name it `interval` and put in the current directory, then you can mark it executable with `chmod +x interval`. Then you can run:

```
./interval paths...
```

Replace *`paths...`* with the actual pathname or pathnames to the files you want to parse. For example:

```
$ ./interval interval-example.txt
7890MNOP
34567890MNOPQRST
```

The way that script works is that, until end of input is reached (i.e., no more lines), it:

- Reads a line, `$pattern`, which is your string with `A` and `B`, and another line, `$text`, which is the string that will be sliced.
- Finds the index of the first `A` in `$pattern` and the first `B` aside from any that may have preceded that first `A`, and stores them in the `$start` and `$stop` variables, respectively.
- Slices out just the part of `$text` whose indices range from `$start` to `$stop`. Perl's `substr` function takes offset and length arguments, which is the reason for the subtraction, and you're including the letter immediately under `B`, which is the reason for adding `1`.
- Prints just that part, followed by a line break.

**If for some reason you'd prefer a short one-line command** that achieves the same thing but is easily pasted in--but also is harder to understand and maintain--then you could use this:

```bash
perl -wple '$i=index $_,"A"; $_=substr <>,$i,index($_,"B",$i)-$i+1' paths...
```

(As before, you have to replace *`paths...`* with the actual pathnames.)

Answer (score 7):

Since you mentioned [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), you can do this with a sed script too:

```
/^x*Ax*Bx*$/{              # If an index line is matched, then
  N                        # append the next (content) line into the pattern buffer
  :a                       # label a
  s/^x(.*\n).(.*)/\1\2/    # remove "x" from the index line start and a char from the content line start
  ta                       # if a subtitution happened in the previous line then jump back to a
  :b                       # label a
  s/(.*)x(\n.*).$/\1\2/    # remove "x" from the index line end and a char from the content line end
  tb                       # if a subtitution happened in the previous line then jump back to b
  s/.*\n//                 # remove the index line
}
```

If you put this all on one command line, it looks like this:

```
$ sed -r '/^x*Ax*Bx*$/{N;:a;s/^x(.*\n).(.*)/\1\2/;ta;:b;s/(.*)x(\n.*).$/\1\2/;tb;s/.*\n//;}' example-file.txt
7890MNOP
34567890MNOPQRST
$
```

`-r` is needed so that `sed` can understand the regex grouping parentheses without extra escapes.

---

FWIW, I don't think this could be done purely with `grep`, though I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: ju-der : really sed can do all of that? wow

Comment: @Campa [Check out the examples in the manual for more like this](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Examples).  But if you really want to be impressed, try playing [sokoban.sed](https://github.com/aureliojargas/sokoban.sed) - a game written entirely in sed :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it in GNU awk:

```
$ gawk 'NR%2 {split($0,a,/[AB]/); FIELDWIDTHS = length(a[1])" "length(a[2])+2; next} {print $2}' file
7890MNOP
34567890MNOPQRST
```

Answer (score 3):

With very simple Python 3 syntax, we can make the following script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

for fname in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(fname) as fd:
        for line in fd:
            if line.startswith('x'):
                start_index = line.find('A')
                end_index = line.rfind('B')
            else:
                print(line[start_index:end_index+1])
```

Which works as so:

```
$ ./croplines.py  input.txt 
7890MNOP
34567890MNOPQRST
```

OP has provided [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but didn't provide other requirements, so based on what they show, we have alternating pattern: first line that starts with "x", then line with data ( in this case numerical, but it doesn't matter for our purpose).

Advantages of this approach are:

- simple/readable syntax and easy to maintain
- no need to worry about POSIX compliance
- if we need something that scales up to multiple files and shorter command-line statements - we already have `for fname in sys.argv[1:]`, and we could even add additional flexibility of specifying patterns on command-line;
- we can add recursive option with `os.walk` module if we want/need to
- if we need to print next line unconditionally (and thus ignore the lines which don't follow the pattern), we could use just `fd.readline()`

```py
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

    import sys

    for fname in sys.argv[1:]:
        with open(fname) as fd:
            for line in fd:

                start_index = 0
                end_index = len(line)-1

                if line.startswith('x'):
                    start_index = line.find('A')
                    end_index = line.rfind('B')+1
                    line = fd.readline()
                    print(line[start_index:end_index])
```

Answer (score 3):

#### We don't know for sure if..

- there might be lines between or before the couples, which are not part of a couple; header? explanation? comment?
- the first line starts with an `x` *by definition*
- the second line of the couple possibly starts with an `x`

To catch all these situations, using `set()`, we can look for lines which *only* exist of (all of) `x`, `A`, `B`. These, we can be positive, are the first lines of our couples.

Thus we get in python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

f = "/path/to/file"

printresult = False

for l in open(f):
    if printresult == True:
        print(l[i[0]:i[1]])
        printresult = False
    elif set(l.strip()) == {"A", "x", "B"}:
        i = [l.index("A"), l.index("B") + 1]
        printresult = True
```

Thus, the output of:

```
Some results of whatever test
-----------------------------
xxxxxxAxxxxxxBxxxxxx
1234567890MNOPQRSTUV
blub or blublub
xxAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxBxxxxxx
1234567890MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
peanutbutter
AxxxxxxxxxxxxxxBxxxxxx
x234567890MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

becomes:

```
7890MNOP
34567890MNOPQRST
x234567890MNOPQR
```